# Kinect SDK - Not recogizing microphone array

Tags: sdk, kinect

I upgraded my machine to Win 7 Windows Home Premium (32 bit). I bought just the Kinect device, no bundle with XBOX. I install the Kinect SDK.
I plug in the Kinect.

When the microphone array driver tries to install itself, it says Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43). Not too specific lol.

It calls it an "unspecified device"

The camera works but the microphone doesn't.

I've tried plugging the Kinect into all 8 usb ports-  all with the same result.

The machine says there's also an unspecified device called Flip CC, but it won't let me get rid of it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: What did you install? Microsoft Research Kinect SDK or the Kinect SDK 1.0?

Comment: I installed the beta (sdk 1.0 was not released when I installed it). I bought the kinect without the xbox. I have not downloaded the new sdk because I'm not going to spend extra money to buy the new hardware - they really should have specified in the announcements that people wouldnt be able to use the sdk without the new hardware!

Comment: You don't need to buy the Kinect for Windows to make it work. Kinect for Xbox 360 works just as well (almost [according to Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/resources.aspx)). All you need to do is to uninstall the beta, then install the SDK 1.0. 
     **Note** that the early kinect apps that work for the beta version may not work with the SDK 1.0.

Comment: Thanks! I misread the sdk description.

Answer (score 0):

My only idea at this point is that you don't have everything installed necessary for the microphone/speech capabilities.  I would review [this readme](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/docs/readme.htm) and report back here.  Be sure to follow it to a T!  There are a lot of libraries to install for Speech.

Comment: Does the speech need to be installed for USB to recognize the device? I tried plugging the Kinect into another Win 7 machine, and it loads the driver for the mic array without problems, so I know that the Kinect is not defective. The first machine was a little older, but it is USB 2.0, so it should work. Maybe I need to get a new usb port?

Comment: No, I imagine it doesn't.  If it appears to work on another machine, then yes, possibly there is a USB issue. I see you posted on the Kinect forums, that was going to be my next suggestion.  Maybe post the details from here into there?

Comment: Figured out what Flip CC is - I have a kvm from belkin and the driver that comes with it is called Flip CC, so when I get home I'm gonna try uninstalling it, and seeing if that allows the Kinect to recognize the mic array.

Comment: any Q - in the Device Manager, once the Kinect drivers are installed correctly, you should see: Microsoft Kinect Audio Array Control, Microsoft Kinect Camera, and Microsoft Kinect Device. see any of those?

Comment: I'm seeing the device and the camera, but not the array. Other forums are saying something about USB Hubs interfering with each other.

Comment: I've looked at the usb stuff in several files (even posted some of their content) - thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/71d1ea19-8033-47c8-845c-51b54cf4e38a